# check if two lists are equal by type Python

Tags: python, python-2.7, types

I want to check if two lists have the same type of items for every index. For example if I have

```
y = [3, "a"]
x = [5, "b"] 
z = ["b", 5]
```

the check should be `True` for `x` and `y`.
The check should be `False` for `y` and `z` because the types of the elements at the same positions are not equal.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Just [`map`](https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/functions.html#map) the elements to their respective [`type`](https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/functions.html#type) and compare those:

```
>>> x = [5, "b"] 
>>> y = [3, "a"]
>>> z = ["b", 5]
>>> map(type, x) == map(type, y)
True
>>> map(type, x) == map(type, z)
False
```

For Python 3, you will also have to turn the `map` generators into proper lists, either by using the [`list`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#func-list) function or with a [list comprehension](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions):

```
>>> list(map(type, x)) == list(map(type, y))
True
>>> [type(i) for i in x] == [type(i) for i in z]
False
```

---

I did some timing analysis, comparing the above solution to that of [@timgeb](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35554318/1639625), using `all` and `izip` and inputs with the first non-matching type in different positions. As expected, the time taken for the `map` solution is almost exactly the same for each input, while the `all` + `izip` solution can be *very* fast or take three times as long, depending on the position of the first difference.

```
In [52]: x = [1] * 1000 + ["s"] * 1000
In [53]: y = [2] * 1000 + ["t"] * 1000 # same types as x
In [54]: z = ["u"] * 1000 + [3] * 1000 # difference at first element
In [55]: u = [4] * 2000                # difference after first half
In [56]: %timeit map(type, x) == map(type, y)
10000 loops, best of 3: 129 µs per loop
In [58]: %timeit all(type(i) == type(j) for i, j in izip(x, y))
1000 loops, best of 3: 342 µs per loop
In [59]: %timeit all(type(i) == type(j) for i, j in izip(x, z))
1000000 loops, best of 3: 748 ns per loop
In [60]: %timeit all(type(i) == type(j) for i, j in izip(x, u))
10000 loops, best of 3: 174 µs per loop
```

Comment: the use of "all(...)" would make it faster, something like @timgeb does

Comment: @fransua Maybe, but you'd have to use `itertools.izip_longest` then, or it will not work with lists with unequal length, and IMHO this just complicates the code (unless the lists are particularly long).

Answer (score 18):

Lazy evaluation with `all`:

```
>>> from itertools import izip
>>> all(type(a) == type(b) for a,b in izip(x,y))
True
```

Use regular `zip` in Python 3, it already returns a generator.

If the lists can have different lengths, just check the length upfront. Checking the length is a very fast O(1) operation:

```
>>> len(x) == len(y) and all(type(a) == type(b) for a,b in izip(x,y))
True
>>> x = [5,"b",'foo']
>>> len(x) == len(y) and all(type(a) == type(b) for a,b in izip(x,y))
False
```

The `and` will be short-circuit evaluated, that means `all` won't even be called if the lengths differ.

Comment: Nice, but does not work with lists with different length... maybe use `itertools.izip_longest` instead?

Comment: Why can't you use `zip` in Python 2?

Comment: @zondo you can, it just produces a list of tuples instead of a generator

Comment: It would still work, though, so I see no necessity for `itertools`.  I don't see that a list of tuples is worse than a generator.

Comment: @tobias_k I thought about `izip_longest`, but what would you use as a fillvalue which cannot be an element of a list? I think just checking the length upfront is better here.

Comment: @zondo a generator is more memory efficient, it can make a big difference when the lists are very large. The generator will also produce only as many tuples as needed.

Comment: All tuples are needed in this case, so I don't think your second point is valid, but for the sake of memory efficiency, I will concede that you have the superior position.

Comment: @zondo no, not all tuples are needed. For `x = [1, 2, 3]` and `y = ['foo', 2, 3]` only the first tuple is needed.

Comment: Boy, you beat my on all sides.  I guess I should just shut up.

Comment: @zondo It's not a contest. You asked why I use `izip` and I explained. :)

Comment: For what it's worth, you can use `type('', (), {})()` as fill value for `iziplongest()`.  It's an object with a type that's guaranteed not to match any other type.  I'm not saying you _should_ use it.  I'm just saying it would work.

Comment: @SvenMarnach heh, that's pretty interesing. Sort of the nan of types.

Answer (score 3):

Another option with lambda:

```
>>> x = [5, "b"]
>>> y = [3, "a"]
>>> z = ["b", 5]
>>> g = lambda t: [type(i) for i in t]
>>> g(x) == g(y)
True
>>> g(x) == g(z)
False
```

Answer (score 2):

It's very simple when you use a generator expression:

```
are_equal = all(type(i) == type(j) for i, j in zip(x, y))
```

In that example, `x` and `y` are the lists you are checking.  If you want something that you can add to:

```
lists = (x, y)
are_equal = all(len(set(type(j) for j in i)) == 1 for i in zip(*lists))
```

In that way, you can just change `lists`, and it will still work.  It works by using the fact that a `set` removes all duplicates.  For each tuple that `zip()` returns, it creates a set of each item's types and checks to see if they have are the same by seeing if the length of the set is 1.

Comment: Your second part does not compare types based on position. Particularly, it shows `true` for `x` and `z`.

Comment: @tobias_k: Oops; I just left out a couple characters.  Fixed now.

Comment: I don't see what you mean.  `set(type(j) for j in i))` gives a set of the type of each element in the current zip tuple.  If the length of that set is not 1, then one of those elements is a different type from the other.  I have tested it, and to all appearances, it works.  Is there something I'm missing?

Comment: You are right, sorry, got confused what the line does and seem to have made a mistake when testing. +1 for a solution that works for comparing the types of an arbitrary number of lists, but for two lists, I think this solution is _very_ hard to comprehend.

Comment: I have attempted to give somewhat of an explanation in my answer.  Is there anything that could potentially be unclear in it?

Answer (score 0):

```
def equalTypes(list1, list2):
    if len(list1) != len(list2):
        return False
    for index, item in enumerate(list1):
        if type(item) != type(list2[index]):
            return False
    return True
```

I just iterate over the list (check if they have same length first) and then when some types mismatch I return False. At the end (no mismatch) I return True.

Answer (score 0):

You can keep the lazy evaluation using `operator.eq` with `itertools` which overall gives you decent average times without storing copies of the lists:

```
In [12]: from itertools import imap, starmap, izip

In [13]: %timeit map(type, x) == map(type, y)
10000 loops, best of 3: 182 µs per loop

In [14]: %timeit all(type(i) == type(j) for i, j in izip(x, u))
1000 loops, best of 3: 239 µs per loop

In [15]: timeit all(type(i) == type(j) for i, j in izip(x, z))
1000000 loops, best of 3: 1.02 µs per loop

In [16]:  %timeit all(type(i) == type(j) for i, j in izip(x, u))
1000 loops, best of 3: 234 µs per loop

In [17]: timeit all(starmap(eq, izip(imap(type, x), imap(type, y))))
1000 loops, best of 3: 238 µs per loop

In [18]: timeit all(starmap(eq, izip(imap(type, x), imap(type, u))))
10000 loops, best of 3: 120 µs per loop

In [19]: timeit all(starmap(eq, izip(imap(type, x), imap(type, z))))
1000000 loops, best of 3: 901 ns per loop
```

If the lists were different lengths, just checking the lengths first ould be the simplest and fastest but if you were to incorporate it into the logic you could use *object* as the *fillvalue* to `itertools.izip_longest`:

```
all(starmap(eq, izip_longest(imap(type, x), imap(type, y), fillvalue=object()))
```