# How to check the values in two dictionaries have the same type?

Tags: python-3.x

For example, I have two dictionaries having the same keys:

```
a = {"a": 1, "b": 2, "c":4.5, "d":[1,2], "e":"string", "f":{"f1":0.0, "f2":1.5}}
b = {"a": 10, "b": 20, "c":3.5, "d":[0,2,4], "e":"q", "f":{"f1":1.0, "f2":0.0}}
```

and I want to compare the types. My code is something like this:

```
if type(a["a"]) ==  type(b["a"]) and type(a["b"]) == type(b["b"]) and type(a["c"]) == type(b["c"]) and type(a["d"]) == type(b["d"]) and type(a["e"]) == type(b["e"]) and type(a["f"]) == type(b["f"]) and type(a["f"]["f1"]) == type(b["f"]["f1"]) and type(a["f"]["f2"]) == type(b["f"]["f2"]):
    first_type = type(b["d"][0])
    if all( (type(x) is first_type) for x in a["d"] )
       #do something
       pass
```

Is there a better way to do it?

Answer (score 2):

You can make a list of the common keys between the dicts:

```
common_keys = a.keys() & b.keys()
```

and then iterate over them to check the types:

```
for k in common_keys:
    if type(a[k]) == type(b[k]):
        print("Yes, same type! " + k, a[k], b[k])
    else: 
        print("Nope! " + k, a[k], b[k])
```

and if you wanted to go deeper, check if any of the items are dicts, rinse an repeat

```
for k in common_keys:

    if type(a[k]) == type(b[k]):
        print("Yes, same type! " + k, type(a[k]), type(b[k]))
        if isinstance(a[k], dict): 
            ck = a[k].keys() & b[k].keys()
            for key in ck:
                if type(a[k][key]) == type(b[k][key]):
                    print("Yes, same type! " + key, type(a[k][key]), type(b[k][key]))
                else: 
                    print("Nope!")
    else: 
        print("Nope! " + k, type(a[k]), type(b[k]))
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use a for loop to iterate through the dicts:

```py
same_types = True
for key in a.keys():
    if type(a[key]) != type(b[key]):
        same_types = False
        break
    # if the value is a dict, check nested value types
    if type(a[key]) == dict:
        for nest_key in a[key].keys():
            if type(a[key][nest_key]) != type(b[key][nest_key]):
                same_types = False
                break
    # if the value is a list, check all list elements
    # I just simply concat two lists together, you can also refer to 
    # https://stackoverflow.com/q/35554208/19322223
    elif type(a[key]) == list:
        first_type = a[key][0]
        for elem in a[key] + b[key]:
            if type(elem) != first_type:
                same_types = False
                break
    if not same_types:
        break

if same_types:
    # do something
```

Answer (score 1):

With the following helper function:

```py
def get_types(obj, items=None):
    """Function that recursively traverses 'obj' and returns
    a list of all values and nested values types
    """
    if not items:
        items = []
    if isinstance(obj, dict):
        for value in obj.values():
            if not isinstance(value, (dict, list, set, tuple)):
                items.append(value)
            else:
                get_types(value, items)
    elif isinstance(obj, (list, set, tuple)):
        for value in obj:
            get_types(value, items)
    else:
        items.append(obj)
    return [type(x) for x in items]
```

You can compare two dictionaries' values types however deeply nested these are, like this:

```py
if get_types(a) == get_types(b):
    print("Each a and b values are of same types")
```

Since, in your example, `a` misses one value for `d` key ([1, 2]) compared to the other dict ([0, 2, 4]), nothing will be printed.

Let's take another example where both dictionaries have the same shape this time, but one value of different type (f2):

```py
a = {"a": 1, "b": [[1, 2], [3, [4]]], "c": {"c1": 0.0, "c2": {"x": "9"}}}
b = {"d": 7, "e": [[2, 1], [5, [7]]], "f": {"f1": 8.9, "f2": {"y": 9}}}

if get_types(a) == get_types(b):
    print("Each a and b values are of same types")
```

Then again, nothing will be printed.

But if you replace `9` by `"9"` in b["f2"]:

```py
a = {"a": 1, "b": [[1, 2], [3, [4]]], "c": {"c1": 0.0, "c2": {"x": "9"}}}
b = {"d": 7, "e": [[2, 1], [5, [7]]], "f": {"f1": 8.9, "f2": {"y": "9"}}}

if get_types(a) == get_types(b):
    print("Each a and b values are of same types")

# Output
# Each a and b values are of same types
```